# How to iterate over this list of pointers in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a `list` of `pair`s with `CString`s and want to iterate over it and use `first` and `second` elements of each `pair` in the `list` inside the `for` loop, but I have a problem with doing that. Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work and help me with the solution?

This is my code:

```
list<pair<CString, CString>*> listSubstStr;
for (std::list<pair<CString, CString>*>::iterator it = listSubstStr.begin(); it != listSubstStr.end(); ++it) {
      CxXML* p = pRoot->AddTag(NOWKT("Pair"));
      p->SetString("First", it->first);
      p->SetString("Second", it->second);
   }
```

Here are the errors:

[image]

Comment: what problem do you have? what is the meaning of "not working"?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, sorry, I forgot to add a picture with errors, I edited the post :)

Comment: please add the error messages as text in the question

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example, with all the code necessary to reproduce the errors including `#includes`. This will help answer questions like: Are `list` and `pair` just `std::list` and `std::pair`, or do they come from somewhere else? Is `CString` a typedef for `char*`, or something else? What is `CxXML` from? These aren't the only things a complete example will help with, which is why we generally ask for that instead of just the specific questions.

Comment: please add a [mre] with compilable source code and the full compiler error message as text from the output window rather than a screenshot of the error messages

Answer (score 3):

It seems you mean

```
  p->SetString("First", ( *it )->first);
  p->SetString("Second", ( *it )->second);
```

That is the expression `*it` has the type `pair<CString, CString>*`.

Also check whether this code is called within a constant member function. If so then you have to use const_iterator instead of iterator.

Comment: Yep. that was the problem. I have to learn more about pointers in C++ :)
I am a beginner.

and what is about this error?  C2440 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'stlp_std::priv::_List_iterator<_Tp,_Traits>' to 'stlp_std::priv::_List_iterator<_Tp,_Traits>'

Comment: @Delprof you rather should learn that most of the times you do not need pointers ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your types.

You're iterating over a `list<pair<CString, CString>*>`, so the elements are `pair<CString, CString>*`.
That means that `*it` is also a pointer, so you need to dereference twice:

```
(*it)->first
```

or use the modern range loop:

```
for (auto element: listSubstStr)
{
      CxXML* p = pRoot->AddTag(NOWKT("Pair"));
      p->SetString("First", element->first);
      p->SetString("Second", element->second);
}
```

(The use of `std::list` and of pointers to pairs are both questionable, by the way. The more common choice would be `vector<pair<CString, CString>>`.)

Comment: Thank you :)

And what is with this error?
C2440 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'stlp_std::priv::_List_iterator<_Tp,_Traits>' to 'stlp_std::priv::_List_iterator<_Tp,_Traits>'

Comment: `const auto* element` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `list<pair<CString, CString>*>` ie a list of pointers to `pair<CString,Cstring>`.

Dereferencing an iterator will get you a `pair<CString, CString>*&`. Hence to get the pair you need to dereference the iterator, then the pointer: `(*it)->first`.

It is rather likely that you didnt need pointers in the first place.

Comment: Thank you :)

And what is with this error?
C2440 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'stlp_std::priv::_List_iterator<_Tp,_Traits>' to 'stlp_std::priv::_List_iterator<_Tp,_Traits>'